# Пустое пространство после RecyclerView, некорректная работа c NestedScrollView

Tags: android, recyclerview, nested-scrollview

Есть RecyclerView(match_parent, 0dp), который размещен внутри NestedScrollView(match_parent, match_parent). Когда параметр recyclerViewUserPhotos.isNestedScrollingEnabled установлен в false, эти два представления взаимодействуют как нужно, кроме одной детали: должны загружаться два изображения, но загружается только одно. Если отключить данный параметр, загружаются оба изображения, но вьюхи прокручиваются независимо.

Вторая проблема заключается в свободном пространстве под RecyclerView. От него у меня никак не получается избавиться.
Layout RecyclerView - ConstraintLayout(match_parent, match_parent)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется, вам надо отказаться от `NestedScrollView` и всё отображать через RecyclerView с помощью разных типов ячеек в нём

Comment: Например использую вот такую отличную обертку - https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter/